# "Invalid aggregate reference." when doing an update with a SUM

Tags: sum, sql-update, firebird, firebird2.5

Good morning, I want to update my table, I want to add the net cost of my product and this net cost is the sum of my unit column + the freight column.

I'm doing the UPDATE like this:;

```
update com_entradas_produtos ep;
set ep.custo_item = sum(ep.unitario + ep.frete);
where ep.empresa = :empresa and ep.codigo = :codigo and ep.produto = :produto;
```

It is returning me the following error:

> SQL error code = -104.
> Invalid aggregate reference.

Could you help me how should I do this update.

Comment: Semicolons are for separating different statements. Remove them from inside the update statement.

Comment: Your code has obvious typos (the presence of `;` where they are syntactically invalid), please fix that. That said, even if you fix the issues with the `;`, the fact remains that you can't use `SUM` like this. What are you trying to do? Use of the aggregate function `SUM` like this makes no sense. Did you mean `ep.unitario + ep.frete`? Please provide a [mre] and explain what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

As [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/466862/mark-rotteveel) outlines in his comment above, aggregate functions like `SUM()` are used to aggregate across rows, but it sounds like you want to just sum multiple columns on each row, so you want something like:

```
update com_entradas_produtos
set ep.custo_item = ep.unitario + ep.frete
where [whatever logic you want]
```